# Create a href link that uses http DELETE verb in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I just started playing with express.js using handlebars.js as my template
I wanted to create a delete link, which should be restful and use http verb DELETE 
instead of GET.

I finally figured out a way to achieve it by creating a link like so below,
adding data-method of delete, and then using jquery on client side to intercept
my link to use DELETE verb.

My link was:

```
<a href="/destroy/{{_id}}" data-method="delete">delete</a>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("a[data-method='delete']").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: this.getAttribute('href'),
        type: 'DELETE'
    })
    return false
})
</script>
```

Is this a recommendable way of achieving this in express.js/handlebars.js?, does anyone have a better way of achieving this?, I haven't been able to find something similar to how rails does it within its helper like:

```
link_to("Destroy", "http://www.example.com", method: :delete)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @tikider I did more research based on your suggestion and came across a middleware called method-override (https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) Since I wanted to handle DELETE your suggestion was quite complete since forms can't send DELETE

This is how I solved it, first I npm installed method-override:

```
sudo npm install method-override --save
```

Attached it to my app middleware handler:

```
// override with POST having ?_method=DELETE
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

Then my view I set my delete buttons as

```
<form method="POST" action="/destroy/{{_id}}?_method=DELETE">
  <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Now every time I click delete it is changed by method-override to DELETE and caught using a middleware like so within my app:

```
app.delete('/destroy/:id', function(req, res) {
   //...
}
```

As I am using handlebars template I can then add it as a helper method.

Comment: Add `const methodOverride = require('method-override')` before `app.use(...`

Answer (score 0):

In your case Rails creates a `form` and sets its method to the one you provided:

> method: symbol of HTTP verb - This modifier will dynamically create an HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the HTTP verb specified.
>   [link_to in Rails Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

your can implement your own in javascript:

```
var link_to = function (text, href, method) {
    return '<form action="' + href + '" method="' + method + '" ><button>'+ text + '</button></form>'
}
```

you can use css to style this button as a normal link.