# Cannot delete mongodb entry with node and handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I tried various ways to delete a entry but no luck. I know I'm close. I did use "post" instead of "delete" with no luck. I did the action request on the html, no luck. Im in a pickle :(

My routers:

```
router.delete('/:id',function(req, res){
  Docket.findById(req.params.id, function(err, docket){
    docket.remove(function(err){
      res.redirect('/dockets');
    });
  });
});
```

Handlebars:

```
<form name="create-docket-form" id="create-docket-form" method="post">
    <div class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete my docket" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you are using method `method="post"`, but your route is listening for DELETE requests: `router.delete('/:id',function(req, res){` So this router is never triggered because the app can't found the route.

I wonder, how do you send your requests, but in if you are using no JavaScript code, you can work around this by applying approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27079539/1290852).

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this problem, first, you have to change the "delete" to "get" in the "router.get()", after that, you go to HandleBars file and put a tag 'button' inside the tag '', put the 'href: '/adress/{{variable to delete}}', go to your node.js and prepare the route, now I'll show you my code:

NODE.EXPRESS / .JS:

```
app.get(`/del-comander/:comand`,express.json() ,(req,res)=>{
    let comanderDel = req.params.comand
    Comander.deleteOne({comander: comanderDel}).then(()=>{
        console.log(`deleted: ${comanderDel}`)
        res.redirect('back')
    }).catch((err)=>{
        res.send(err)
    })
}),
```

HANDLEBARS:

```
{{#each comanders}}
    <strong> comander: </strong>{{comander}} <br>
    <strong> skill: </strong>{{skill}} <br>
    <strong>season: </strong>{{season}} <br>
    <a href='/del-comander/{{comander}}'><button>delete</button></a> 
    <br>
    <hr>
{{/each}}
```

OBS: the args inside '{{}}' was connected with the DataBase, I also did more than just delete the data and printed it to the screen, so each data could be deleted separately, I do not know if my answer was good, but somebody else could have this same problem if you want more code just ask.